# MySQL Update Based on ID Slow (150,000 records)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance

I'm trying to update a table based on the id on another table but I'm having some performance issue. I have 150,000 rows on table_to_update, and 400,000 rows on table_to_get_data.

Table to Update

`+----+-----------------+
| id | field_to_update |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | orange          |
|  2 | apple           |
|  3 | pear            | 
|  1 | orange          |
+----+-----------------+`

Table to Get Data

`+----+-----------------+
| id | field           |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | orange          |
|  2 | apple           |
|  3 | pear            | 
+----+-----------------+`

So I've tried 3 different ways:

Method 1:

```
UPDATE table_to_update t1, table_to_get_data t2
SET t1.field_to_update = t2.field
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Method 2:

```
UPDATE table_to_update
JOIN table_to_get_data
ON table_to_update.id = table_to_get_data.id
SET table_to_update.field_to_update = table_to_get_data.field
```

Method 3:

```
UPDATE table_to_update
LEFT JOIN table_to_get_data
ON table_to_update.id = table_to_get_data.id
SET table_to_update.field_to_update = table_to_get_data.field
```

So far, Method 3 seems to be the fastest, however, calculating the time it would take to update 1000 rows, it will take me 12 hours to finish updating the entire table. Is there a more efficient method to update the table?

EDIT:
Added EXPLAIN table
[EXPLAIN Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtrS0.png)

Comment: Are the columns indexed as they should be? You can also try to run an `EXPLAIN <query>` to see how the query will get executed.

Comment: Show your create table query and also run Explain before each three sql methods.

Comment: Show us the EXPLAIN of your queries

Comment: Thanks, the EXPLAIN table can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rtrS0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Index on columns you have joined from both the tables.

It will make wonders for you.

Comment: I haven't added any indexes, but according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp), indexes are great for searching, but can take more time for updating.

Comment: I dont agree with that.
Add an index and try it yourself.
you can always remove index if not helping.

Comment: Sure, will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wow, adding the index has turned a 12 hour query to less than 10 seconds! Thanks!!

Comment: "Indexes are great for searching" -- You are searching in `table_to_get_data`.  "but take more time for updating" -- This is _much_ less important than the other.